# Carathéodory's convex hulls theorem and Radon partitions

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

Wikipedia's article about [Radon's theorem and its related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%27s_theorem#Related_concepts) states:

> Carathéodory's theorem states that any point in the convex hull of some set of points is also within the convex hull of a subset of at most d + 1 of the points; that is, that the given point is part of a Radon partition in which it is a singleton.

But what about four points in the plane arranged like the vertices of a square? Each one belongs to the convex hull of the four points. But there is no way to take one point and have a Radon partition, isn't it? Am I wrong, or is the article wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, and the part following "that is," is misleading. Your statement about the vertices of a square is correct.

The intended meaning surely is the following: For *any* set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with convex hull $C$ and any point $p \in C \setminus S$ there are $d+1$ points $\{x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}\}$ from $S$ such that $\{p\}$ and $\{x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}\}$ form a Radon partition of $\{p,x_1,\dots,x_{d+1}\}$.

Comment: One should assume that $S$ is not contained in a proper affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$.